# ClientWebPart.aspx does not load the Sharepoint Core.js

Tags: javascript, napa

I have a problem with developing an app for sharepoint.

While the Default.aspx works fine, the ClientWebPart.aspx does not. 
I load the whole SharepointJSFiles with

```
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" />
```

before i also tried with

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script> -->
```

I call my function with:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
```

in the loadUserData function i create a clientContext with

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

as mentioned - when I do this within my Default.aspx file everything works fine,
but in the ClientWebPart.aspx it tells me:

*Unable to get property 'get_current' of undefined or null reference*

Although it is nearly the same code.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reference the Scripts different in the ClientWebPart.aspx than in the Default.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I solved it on my own - 
i referenced the Scripts manually (Although I am not sure which of these I really need for my operation) and now it works.

If someone may has the same issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/mQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `sp.js` and `sp.runtime.js` libraries for `ClientContext`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```